# from code loop to Sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, ms-access

Edit:
I edit the post, to add some complexity. What if the box would contain repeated barcodes?  Barcode 222222222222 exists twice in the box. And in the main table (or the warehouse) exists 3 times.
How would be the query so I delete only 2 barcodes?

The answer I chose groups the barcodes of the box, thus, only deletes one of each.

Hello all,

```
I have this table

Barcodes
+--+------------------+-------+
|ID|Barcode           |DELETE |
+--+------------------+-------+
|1 | 11111111111111   |  0    | 
|2 | 22222222222222   |  0    |
|3 | 22222222222222   |  0    |
|4 | 22222222222222   |  0    |
|5 | 33333333333333   |  0    |
|6 | 33333333333333   |  0    |
|7 | 33333333333333   |  0    |
|8 | 44444444444444   |  0    |
+--+------------------+-------+
```

ID is an autoincremental field.

Each line is a barcode which represents 1 unit of the same item. For example, I have 3 items represented by barcode 33333333333333

Everytime any user scans a barcode, and it matches, I mark the barcode to be deleted when the process is finished.

```
update barcodes
set delete=-1
where id=(select max(barcode) as maxi from barcodes where barcode like 'x' and delete>-1)
```

This works fairly fast. But sometimes, instead of scanning the items one by one, the user may scan a box which contains up to 150 items.
The back-end is a mysql table in a remote server, and the front-end is ms access.

```
BOX 
    +------------------+
    |Barcode           |
    +------------------+ 
    | 22222222222222   |
    | 22222222222222   |
    | 33333333333333   |
    | 44444444444444   |
    +------------------+
```

I use a loop, and for each item in the box, I repeat the sql query, but this takes up to 3 minutes for the 150 items box because of latency.

Do you know any kind of query that would update my barcodes tables with those in the read box?

The output of it would be something like:

```
+--+------------------+-------+
|ID|Barcode           |DELETE |
+--+------------------+-------+
|1 | 11111111111111   |  0    | 
|2 | 22222222222222   | -1    |
|3 | 22222222222222   |  0    |
|4 | 33333333333333   | -1    |
|5 | 33333333333333   |  0    |
|6 | 33333333333333   |  0    |
|7 | 44444444444444   | -1    |
+--+------------------+-------+
```

If the sale is finished, I would just delete those marked as delete=-1

Comment: @GordonLinoff "The back-end is a mysql table in a remote server, and the front-end is ms access."

Comment: that is right, the solution could affect either ms-access or mysql (or both, I don't know yet), thus I added both tags

Comment: so you are saying that you may choose to have an ms-access data set someday, so you want a solution to be in both languages

Comment: no; I am just informing how the set up is.

Answer (score 0):

What is the datatype of barcode? Avoid grouping to speed up updates. Note you are not deleting anything despite use of a column with that name. Remove `like` and `>` in the sql and replace them with `=` logic with something like the following for mysql server side code:

```
update barcodes
set delete=-1
where id=(select id from barcodes where barcode='x' and delete=0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

You'll have to adjust the above to suit the specifics of `x` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to pick the `id` values of the rows to be deleted:

```
SELECT MIN(id)
FROM Barcodes AS b1
INNER JOIN BOX AS b2 ON b1.Barcode = b2.Barcode
WHERE `DELETE` <> -1
GROUP BY b1.Barcode
```

If you use the above `SELECT` query in your original `UPDATE` query, then you have what you need:

```
UPDATE Barcodes
SET `DELETE` = - 1
WHERE id IN ( SELECT minID 
              FROM (SELECT MIN(id) AS minID
                    FROM Barcodes AS b1
                    INNER JOIN BOX AS b2 ON b1.Barcode = b2.Barcode
                    WHERE `DELETE` <> -1
                    GROUP BY b1.Barcode) AS t )
```

The above works in MySQL. See [**demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9158a/1).

Note that you need to wrap the `SELECT` query in a sub-query, since MySQL doen't let you specify target table `'Barcodes'` for update in `FROM` clause.

Comment: great! that sounds great. Thank you very much

Comment: Well I thought that would work, but as soon as the box contains repeated barcodes, only one would be deleted from the mail table.

Comment: @Fran This is a completely different requirement from the one posted originally in the OP. I think you should better post a different question instead of editing this one.